# Git - accept push only from a named repository

Tags: git

Is it possible to configure a bare Git repository in a way that will only allow push from one or more named other repositories and reject push from others.

EDIT: Apologies, should have mentioned that, but the target repository (the one being pushed to) is served via git: protocol only and I can't change this. So, unfortunately I can't use ssh keys...

Comment: I humbly suggest that you consider changing your hosting if the git:// protocol is the only choice for *pushing*. It's really meant for public *read* access; it doesn't do any sort of authentication for write (push) access. As the git-daemon manpage says "there is no authentication in the protocol (in other words, anybody can push anything into the repository, including removal of refs). This is solely meant for a closed LAN setting where everybody is friendly." Fortunately, it's easy enough to clone your repo somewhere else with more secure options.

Comment: P.S. You can quite easily still have the git protocol available for read access, while using ssh or https for push access. For example, gitolite+git-daemon will easily get you ssh access controls for push, and open read access via the git protocol.

Comment: It is a "closed LAN setting where everybody is friendly". It's not so much security I'm worried it, as it is people accidentally pushing to the wrong place and breaking the workflow. It may well be the case the we've made the wrong choice with the git protocol, but that's what I'm trying to establish....

Comment: "friendly" means "no one will ever mess anything up" - and your question implies that there's concern someone will. You don't have to have active malicious intent for someone to do somethin unfriendly! There's really not much overhead in setting up something like gitolite, and it'll let you do fancy things like "these users can push to these branches but not these branches", which sounds like exactly what you want. (And the only change everyone will see will be changing `git://server/path/to/repo` to `gitolite@server:repo`)

Comment: OK, fair enough, gitolite looks interesting. So does gerrit by the way. And I guess the one answer I got answers the original question as well, so I'm going to mark this answered. I guess the real answer is there's many options to consider and I need to do a bit more homework to find the best suited for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with SSH keys if you are willing to add a user on the machine. Gitorious or Github would also work, as would a fantastic custom SSH `LocalCommand`. But the general principle is that you create a keypair which is authorized on the account holding the repo. If you think about it, the name of a repository is used to fetch from and push to it. If you are on the receiving end of a push, you don’t have the same information.